# Does EF4 support mapping 1 component from several tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

At my company we have a database with one table being so big that it was splitted into 3 tables. They all share an ID and the info is NOT normalized so there is info for several entities in the tables, some entities actually have some fields in one table and some fields in the other tables.

There is a new project and they want to use nHibernate to map it, so that the code uses the  ORM and we work on objects rather than query strings.

One of the problems we are having is that we are using nHibernates fluent "join" to map the 3 tables into one, but nHibernate won't let you map components inside joins, also it seems liek you cant  map components that are split several tables.

Is Entity Framework 4 capable of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. So does EF 1. It's called [entity splitting](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-entity-splitting/).

Comment: Little on the short side, but it was a good place to start looking for info, thanks!

Comment: As any evil overlord wizard worth his salt knows, once you know something's true name, you can control it.